# Change type of an array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have this type of array:

```
0: Client
clientId: 405229
clientName: "Test, Jamie"
1: Client
clientId: 405288
clientName: "Test1, Jamie"
2: Client
clientId: 405239
clientName: "Test3, Jamie"
```

and I basically want to convert it to be a plain array without the class like

```
0:
clientId: 405229
clientName: "Test, Jamie"
1:
clientId: 405288
clientName: "Test1, Jamie"
2: 
clientId: 405239
clientName: "Test3, Jamie"
```

I have tried doing:

```
Array.map(x=> new Array(x))
```

but that produce the same result.

any help?

Comment: What do you mean when you're saying *'but that produce the same result'*? Can you share a piece of code that doesn't work/causes typescript compilation errors? FWIW, `Array.map(x=> new Array(x))` does nothing useful because `Array` is a built-in object

Comment: I basically want to return a flat array of just KeyValue pair and not a concrete class

Comment: I evened out your downvote and provided a straightforward answer below. IMHO it was an interesting enough question for me to add the frag to my scrap widget in my mono repo.

Comment: You could just do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clientArray))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice functional-ish ES6-ish way of going about it:

```
    // Make the typed array
    const clients : Array<Client> = [];
    for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      clients.push ( new Client ( i, 'client_' + i.toString () ) );
    }

    // This is the magic line, just spread the object
    const plain = clients.map ( x => ( { ...x } ) );

    // First logs as a typed array, 
    // second as just plain old objects
    console.log ( clients );
    console.log ( plain );
```

[image: Trace of arrays]

Comment: that's the answer!  you are a life savior

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it work for any Object I would use the javascript `Object.keys` which will return  you all the object's own property names , read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Then create an function that will map any class object.

```
let clientArray : Client[] = [ 
  new Client(24, 'Kobe'), 
  new Client(23, 'Lebron James'),
  new Client(1, 'Zion Williams')
]
let productsArray : Product[] = [ 
  new Product(24, 'Sneakers'), 
  new Product(23, 'Bling),
]

// use this function to map any class to to a simple object.
function mapToSimple(client){ 
    let keys = Object.keys(client)
    let result = {}
    keys.forEach((key) => {
        result[key] = client[key];
    })
    return result;
};

let results = clientArray.map(mapToSimple)
let anotherResults = productsArray.map(mapToSimple)
console.log(results);
console.log(anotherResults);
```

Comment: What exactly is `Array` here?

Comment: the problem is that the objects of the array aren't always known hence the need remove class type

Answer (score 0):

Mapping an array of `Client`s to an array of `Client` attributes needs the provided function to the map method to pick out the attributes. e.g.

Say there is the following `Client` class:

```
class Client {
   clientId: Number;
   clientName: string;

   constructor(clientId: Number, clientName: string) {
      this.clientId = clientId;
      this.clientName = clientName;
   }
}
```

And there is an initial array of Client instances.

```
const clientInstances  : Client[] = [ 
  new Client(1, 'Raymond'), 
  new Client(2, 'Damond') 
]

console.log(clientInstances);
// [ Client { clientId: 1, clientName: 'Raymond' },
//   Client { clientId: 2, clientName: 'Damond' } ]
```

The function provided to the map method is passed each client instance and a new object returned with the client attribute value set for the related key.

```
interface IClient { 
    clientName: string;
    clientId: Number; 
}

const clientObjects : IClient[] = clientInstances.map(
  client => (
    { clientName: client.clientName, clientId: client.clientId }
  )
)

console.log(clientObjects);
// [ { clientName: 'Raymond', clientId: '1' },
//   { clientName: 'Damond', clientId: '2' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

- For a Pure TS solution where all you care about is the type just [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) it

```
class Client {
   clientId: number;
   clientName: string;

   constructor(clientId: number, clientName: string) {
      this.clientId = clientId;
      this.clientName = clientName;
   }
}

type ClientArray = Client[];
type JustValues = Pick<Client, 'clientId' | 'clientName'>[]
```

If you know you want to include all of the values from the Class/interface you can do

```
type JustValues = Pick<Client, keyof Client>[]
```

[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCIEsCmA7ALtA3gKGn0y6AkgCYBc0KArgLYBGSATgNy76KpoByYNSFENIwQoA5qzbRgAexSDGVYGmmMAFAU6kK1ekwA0Ujuh58BQkaICUWSXmhoAFgggA6DcRLQAvIcJpSrHZ2js5uRty8SN6+nCZIgXgAvtjJ2GgAngAOUfB+AIKMjGDp0bmcANoAuqwZ2dAAUlSCAGpgIFRIMD4ACgjAANYAPGXoBv1I6dIAZnDhAHxV2GlZOeFEaEg0peEFRenlAAyVy3Wt7UgIG1s+jS1tHRCHlUA)